# Loading QT in Visual Studios

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt

I have to load QT in Visual Studios 2010 for a Graphics class. I'm having trouble with the installation.

The professor says we'll need the QT Open Source Library for Visual Studios:
      qt-win-opensource-4.8.3-vs2010.exe (240mb)

And the QT Visual Studios add-in.

I found the add-in on QT's website, but I couldn't find the first installer. Someone please help!! I can't start my assignment until I get this working :(

Answer (score 0):

Is it [here](http://download.qt-project.org/archive/qt/4.8/4.8.3/qt-win-opensource-4.8.3-vs2010.exe) what you are looking for?